# Display grid center child elements horizontally

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm sure this has been answered before but I can't seem to get it working. I'm trying to horizontally center grid items with a `display:grid` parent. I've got a 12 column grid (76px column / 56px gap at full screen), with various column width child elements (for this example I'll just use `span 8` 1000px).

```css
.main-container{
  max-width:1528px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 56px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.grid-8{
  grid-column: span 8;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="grid-8">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also once the child element is centred is it possible for it to keep its width (1000px) until the `.main-container` starts to touch either side? once the browser starts to get pulled smaller (horizontally). Sorry, this is a little tricky for me to explain what I mean. The `.main-container` if the browser window is pulled in so this is at say 1200px wide the `span 8` column will no longer be 1000px wide it will have shrunk (I'm guessing because it is relative to the main container size). But ideally, I'd like it to stay 1000px until the .main-container hits it and then the `span 8` can start reducing in width.

Thanks

Comment: Your element is center, but you've told it to be 100% of the width, taking 8 of the columns. With nothing in the other columns, this means the element is the same width as the parent. Also, the content of your element hasn't been aligned, so will always appear to the left of your element (assuming LTR here, otherwise it will always appear to the right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't align items in **grid** automatically with **justify/align** props.

You can try using **grid-column-end: -N;** syntax for each child nodes, but it's not best way to do that.

Much better to use **flex** - in this case you can align child nodes as you wish.

Anyway, if you want to continue working with grid, you can do something like this (like an option):

```css
.main-container {
  max-width: 1528px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  --columns-amount: 12;
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns-amount), 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 56px;
  /*justify-items: center;*/
}

.grid-8 {
  /* edit --column-size to see changes */
  --column-size: 8;
  grid-column: calc((var(--columns-amount) - var(--column-size)) / 2 + 1) / span var(--column-size);
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}


/* flex */

.parent--flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent--flex>.grid-8 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 66.66667%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="grid-8">Grid</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="parent--flex">
    <div class="grid-8">Flex</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll have a play around with the grid options you've suggested. I did figure I could do using flex. But because it's very grid-based I thought the better option would have been to use display:grid. Thanks for taking the time to reply.